# Find the directional derivative of function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

$$f(x,y) = 
    \begin{cases}
    \displaystyle
    \frac{x^{3}-3xy^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}, 
    & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
    0 , & (x,y) = (0,0)
    \end{cases}$$

Find the directional derivative in $(0,0)$ such that makes an angle $135°$ with $x$ positive direction.

My attempt:

$\lim_{h\to 0}f_x(0+h,0)=\frac{\frac{(0+h)^3-3(0+h)0^2}{(0+h)^2+0^2}-f(0,0)}{h}=1$

$\lim_{h\to 0}f_y(0,0+h)=\frac{\frac{(0)^3-3(0)(0+h)^2}{(0)^2+(0+h)^2}-f(0,0)}{h}=0$

The directional derivative is $(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$, i have to normalize the vector , so $(-1,1)$.

The directional derivative is $(1,0)(-1,1)=-1$

My solution isn't correct , I can't get why , hope for some help , thanks !

Comment: as a start (-1,1) is not normalized

Comment: Than I guess to proceed like you did you would need before to prove that the function is differentiable in the origin?

Comment: I think what the question wants is to find the directional derivative in $(0,0)$ when going there from the straight line $(x,y(x))$ which makes an angle of $135°$ with the horizontal axis, and positive direction likely refers to staying above the horizontal axis while doing that. So you're not looking for your limit I think but for something of the type $\lim_{h \to 0} f_\cdot(h,y(h))$ with the correct $y$ I'd assume?

Comment: @BrunoB Yes , I have no idea how to approach the problem.

Comment: @Thomas you are right , i didnt prove that the function is differentiable

Comment: First try to find the equation of the straight line in question. You're given an angle, and as such you know one point that belongs to the line using the sine and cosine of said angle. Then, just do what you did with the standard directional derivatives: I could be wrong, but what you want to do is to take the limit when $h \to 0^+$ in $$\frac{f(h,y(h)) - f(0,0)}{h}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $v=(v_1,v_2)$ a direction of $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}(0,0)=\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{f(0+tv_1,0+tv_2)-f(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{(tv_1)^3-3tv_1(tv_2)^2}{(tv_1)^2+(tv_2)^2}=\dfrac{v_1^3-3v_1v_2^2}{v_1^2+v_2^2}$$
Now you can substituite.
Alternatively, you check if $f$ is differentiable in $(0,0)$; if so you can use the following formula:
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x_0,y_0)=\langle\nabla f(x_0,y_0),v\rangle$$

Comment: (+1) what do you get if you suppose the function to be differentiable (even if without proving it beforehand) ?

Comment: Not sure I understood properly your question :(

Comment: I was just curious what the final formula you wrote compares with the limit

Comment: If they are different than it would suffice to prove that the function is not differentiable

Comment: Nice remark actually

Comment: @SineoftheTime $v$ has to be a normalize vector ?

Comment: Yes, the term "direction" refers to a normalised vector. Maybe is not the case in Enlish, but in my language it is.